# Custom LookAt and what's the math behind it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, linear-algebra, trigonometry

I've been trying to understand the math (trigonometry and linear algebra) behind the `transform.LookAt()` function. I followed a tutorial and tried to modify it to fit my needs, but I haven't succeeded so far.

I'm trying to achieve a camera (in 3d space) that is following a player with a custom offset but at the same time the user can zoom the camera in and out all while still having that `Vector3` offset. I'm also locking the other axes, and just only want to apply the rotation to the X axis. The problem with my script is that the angle seems to be clamped between `45°` and `90°`  degrees. I think I'm missing something

```
private void LookAt(Transform t) 
{
    Vector3 forward = _camPos - (t.position + new Vector3(0, t.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().height / 2, 0));
    Debug.DrawRay(forward, -forward, Color.blue);
    Vector3 right = Vector3.Cross(target.up, forward);
    Debug.DrawRay(forward, right, Color.magenta);
    Vector3 newUp = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.forward, right);
    Debug.DrawRay(forward, newUp, Color.yellow);

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(forward.magnitude, newUp.magnitude) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    mainCam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(angle, 0, 0);
}
```

- My code first get's the forward vector (**hypotenuse** in a right triangle) from the camera to the target. Side note here, that this gives the opposite direction, but it doesn't matter because
- it then calculates the "right" vector by having the cross product of the forward vector and the target's up vector
- then it calculates the "newUp" vector (**opposite** in a right triangle) by having the cross product of the forward and right vector
- calculates the X rotation by using **Arcus tangent** which is the ratio between the **hpyotenuse/opposite**

As you can see, the vector calculations are right like on the screenshot

- **blue** -forward vector
- **magenta** right vector
- **yellow** newUp vector

forward, right and newUp vectors

[image]

Still, the camera is only focusing on the character properly when I decrease the zoom rate, a.k.a moving the camera closer to it:

Only looking at the target (properly) after a distance

[image]

What am I missing? Help greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Didn't this come up the other day? There's plenty of examples of chase _cameras in Unity._  Pretty sure there's one in Standard Assets.

Comment: I know that there's Quaternion.LookRotation() and Transform.LookAt(), but I wanted to know the math behind it for learning purposes. Every post I checked were telling the same thing but not explain the math at all

Comment: From a mathematical point of view im aure the internet has finding angles between two points.

Comment: I would make sure all the vectors are normalized. I also despise euler angles, So I would just set your forward/right/up vectors as rows/columns (I wont bother to lookup witch) of a matrix4x4, that can then be converted to a quaternion (that probably also need to be normalized). That way you can be sure the rotation *exactly* corresponds to your vectors, no messing about with euler angles.

Comment: _"but I wanted to know the math behind it for learning purposes. Every post I checked were telling the same thing but not explain the math at all"- [a quick search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix).   See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

Comment: Thanks JonasH for the actual helpful answer. I'll take a shot at what you said later and get back to you if it was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an actual answer. It looks like you got the correct idea, i.e. taking the cross-product between the look-at direction and an arbitrary up-vector, and then another cross product to ensure all the vectors are orthogonal. I'm not sure I understand exactly what the offset does, but I assume that is working as intended. There are a few things I would do:

1. Make sure everything is normalized, I do not think this is strictly necessary, but it helps to keep values small.
2. Add a check to handle if the forward direction and the target.up is close to parallel, and either pick some other up-vector, or give an error so you can detect the problem.
3. Construct a rotation matrix directly.

I strongly prefer to handle rotations as vectors, quaternions or matrices. I find euler angles confusing and difficult to use since there are multiple variants that apply the rotations in different order, and they are difficult to visualize.

A rotation matrix (i.e. 3x3) are in practice just three orthogonal vectors, this is also super useful way to visualize matrices. I *think* each vector should correspond to a *row* in the matrix, but I'm not familiar with unity, and the conventions can be different.

And a 4x4 matrix is just a rotation matrix + a column for translation and an extra row. So just use [SetRow](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.SetRow.html) (Or SetColumn) for each of your forward/right/up vectors, using a 0 for the w-value of the vector 4. You can then [convert the matrix to a quaternion](https://answers.unity.com/questions/11363/converting-matrix4x4-to-quaternion-vector3.html), I can't fund such a builtin function in unity, and that seem a bit odd, but the link should show the principle, and there should be many other articles that show the math behind it.

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer, especially for the links and to use 0s for w values, because I'm still at the beginning of learning math for 3d. I accepted your answer because based on the info you provided, I should be able to get by!